# AWS Java SDK not working on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I installed the AWS Toolkit in Eclipse on Windows. Everything works except for the "Start New Java Project". When I select this option, nothing happens. The New AWS JAva Project does open the first time after installing the AWS Toolkit but it only report that the AWS Java SDK is being installed and does not let me create a new project.

I tried on two different computers and verified that the AWS Java SDK was installed.

I tried this with and without installing the Android SDK.

In the "AWS SDK For Java" preference, I tried all sorts of options for the "SDK directory". To no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It happens only because of your **incompatibility of AWS toolkit** and your eclipse version. So add url of eclipse plugin as per version of eclipse.
This will solve your problem.!
follow this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems that some versions of eclipse have had issues (during upgrades) with AWS toolkit as noted by AWS [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html)

> Some versions of Eclipse, (notably Mars and Neon), may fail to fetch the latest artifacts due to a bug in old versions of the Oomph plugin. To work around this issue:
>
> - Make sure that you're using https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/site.xml as the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse update site.
> - Delete the ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache/ directory to remove cached content.
> - Install the latest version of Oomph (Eclipse Installer).

I was using Eclipse Mars Java EE linux x86_64 version and faced similar issues where wizard for new AWS lambda project, for example, never completes.

I have retried the same wizard in Eclipse Oxygen Java linux86_64 version and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use maven to grab the AWS SDK.

Check out this blog, follow back up with issues...

http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/amazon-web-services-and-platform-as_11.html